# replacement for in query list mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a mysql query which goes like this(I have simplified it )

```
Select A.a ,B.b
from A,B
where
A.c = B.c
and A.d in (100,121,134,155,132... )
```

There are generally about 1000 entries in the IN condition . Is there a way to speed this up given that the IN performance in MySQL is bad.

Comment: Put the list in temp table and `Join`  with your query. Also start using `INNER JOIN` instead of old style depreciated comma separated join

Comment: Is there an index on `A.d`?

Comment: And don't use comma style JOINs

Comment: There are many aspects of optimization -- I don't want to answer your question because it may be "over-simplified"; hence the advice may not apply.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a particular range for column A.d (say x to y), you may try this:

```
SELECT A.a, B.b FROM A
JOIN B ON
A.c = B.c
WHERE A.d BETWEEN x AND y;
```

Comment: This is a great answer... for a different question